# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bayesianpy (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for bayesianpy

Tags: python

While executing the command

```
pip install bayesianpy
```

I'am getting the error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bayesianpy
>   (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for bayesianpy.

Comment: Paste the output of `pip install -vvv bayesianpy`.

Comment: A [search for this package on pypi](https://pypi.org/search/?q=bayesianpy) returns: `There were no results for 'bayesianpy'.` It's just you're trying to install a package that simply does not exist on pypi. A package of such name exists on github, but you'll probably need to `git clone` it then, not `pip install` it.

Comment: Im having the same problem, becuse I trying to install a library somebody made in github.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this command

> pip install bayesian-optimization

Answer (score 0):

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bayesianpy
>   (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for bayesianpy.

This simply means  the package you are trying to install is not present on repo(pypi)

There is another case where your certificates have some issues. then you may get the same error even if requested package exists on pypi. But here that is not a case.